# Trigger event when user scroll to position 300 from top?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using reactjs and trying to change style of a Div when user scroll from top to position (top + 300px). If scrolling down from this position, it will `display: block` else is `none`. How do I do this with react? I searched here but all results are not answered mine.

I tried some methods with useRef, handleOnScroll like below function but it doesn't work.

```js
const handleScroll = (e) => {
  const scrolledFromTop = contentRef.current?.scrollTop;
  setActive(scrolledFromTop > 300);
};
```

```
<div ref={contentRef} onScroll={handleScroll}> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might solve your problem:

```
const handleScroll = (e) => {
  setActive(e.currentTarget.scrollTop > 300);
};
```

Comment: I endup with your answer, thank you> I have to use `addEventListener` to make it works. Use `ref={contentRef} onScroll={handleScroll}` doesn't work for me.

Comment: I forgot to say but `onScroll={handleScroll}` should be on the element being scrolled. If that was already the case I don't see why it didn't work. Anyway, I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

use `window.scrollY` to watch scroll distance.

```js
const handleScroll = (e) => {
    setActive(window.scrollY > 300);
};
```